# Postmaster user defined hooks & member registration

Tags: members, postmaster, registration

EE 2.5.5. Postmaster 1.2. FreeMember 2.1.1

The predefined hooks (some of which are named differently in the docs) don't contain one for member registration. So I'm using a user defined hook and entering:

```
member_member_register
```

But when submitting a new member form I get a blank page after just under a minute. Everything works fine without that Postmaster Hook.

I should mention that member accounts are automatically activated, which is one reason why we can't use the standard EE emails. Also, no info related to this hook appears in exp_postmaster_mailbox.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I will take a look at this later today and get back with you. I should have a member_member_register hook available (I know I have written one even if it's not in the core add-on). I will also fix any naming inconsistencies, so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @JustinKimbrell, thanks. If you can't put EE hooks in that user defined hooks box, what goes there?

Comment: No, that is the exact intent. You should be able to do it, but if it's not working right then there could be a bug. Do you have PHP debugging enabled and if so, are there any errors?

Comment: @JustinKimbrell, I'm not getting anything in the server error_log. I'll try to replicate this on a testing install.

Comment: @JustinKimbrell, I can replicate the problem, but again with no errors. Interestingly the user is created and the new member notification sent to admin. This seems to indicate some sort of hang in Postmaster. If you add a debug mode to Postmaster that dumps to the server error log I'll send you whatever it outputs.

Comment: @Justin Kimbrell, any word on a fix to this yet?